# My script is not working for bootstrap treeview

Tags: php, jquery, json, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to connect the bootstrap treeview but the json script is not working.  here is the fetch.php source code:  `

```
$sub_data["id"] = $row["id"];
$sub_data["invited"] = $row["invited"];
$sub_data["text"] = $row["invited"];
$sub_data["caller_id"] = $row["caller_id"];
$data[] = $sub_data;

foreach ($data as $key => &$value)
{
    $output[$value["id"]] = &$value;
}
foreach ($data as $key => &$value)
{
    if ($value["caller_id"] && isset($output[$value["caller_id"]]))
    {
        $output[$value["caller_id"]]["nodes"][] = &$value;
    }
}
foreach ($data as $key => &$value)
{
    if ($value["caller_id"] && isset($output[$value["caller_id"]]))
    {
        unset($data[$key]);
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);`
```

and this is the treeshow.php script code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "fetch.php",
        method:"POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#treeview').treeview({data: data});
        }
    });

});
```

and mysql db fields: `id, invited, caller_id` what is wrong with this codes?

Comment: Have you checked `console error` ?

Comment: Yes of course :|

Comment: do `console.log(data)` inside `ajax` success then check browser console, let me know what returned

Comment: There is nothing in console and the data returns nothing!

Comment: tnx Pedram i solved it.